# cannot launch node of type [arbotix_python/arbotix_driver]: arbotix_python

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i run :
roslaunch rbx2_bringup   pi_robot_with_gripper.launch sim:=true

i have this error :
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [arbotix_python/arbotix_driver]: arbotix_python
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/jade/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/jade/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/jade/stacks
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [arbotix_controllers/gripper_controller]: arbotix_controllers

please help me .  how can i fix that ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243919/cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Barbotix_python/arbotix_driver%5D:-arbotix_python/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhaoxuan120](https://answers.ros.org/users/28053/zhaoxuan120/) on 2016-09-23**:
I have the same error. Do you fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try to do this to check

```
roscd arbotix_python
```

If you can't roscd the package, in other words, you don't install this package at all!

Then install  the package, arbotix, shown in the error:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-arbotix
```

Hope it helps

---

Originally posted by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) with karma: 339 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1